# Style sheet CSS not showing

Tags: css

I cannot get style sheets, template type CSS, to display.
All I get is a 404 error when I attempt to view a CSS file, js works fine.

http://mydomain.com/?css=style/mycss

Displays a 404 error

Running under Apache2, error log appears to be no help.
I was thinking this looks like a permission error, but no seeing that js works.

ExpressionEngine v2.9.0 - Build Date: 20140715

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: is there a reason to run your CSS through ExpressionEngine?

Answer (score 1):

Your url adress is not correct,  to display your css file, you have to set the related path:

Mydomain/path/file.css

An example: 
Domain.com/main/color.css

No need to put ?css=, it will give you a 404 error.

But why do you want to display a css file?

If you use a css template you have to insert the template path inside the page header.

href="{stylesheet='channel/channel_css'}"

Comment: It is working?? try to have a look here: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/stylesheet.html

Comment: Hello Stéphane, 1) the URL is directly from EE, Templates > Template Groups > Style (my template group name) > View. 2) http://mydomain.com/style/mycss gives me the same results, as does href="{stylesheet='channel/channel_css'}" 3) Agreed about using EE for CSS, but sometimes I want to do quick testing and templates come in handy. 5) I will check out the link next. Thanks.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="{stylesheet='channel/channel_css'}" /> Gives 404. I'm going to do a clean install as I have no idea what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Now i understand your css path. It's html code created by EE. So i've created a template too inside the html header:

No problems related, when i show the code source it appears:

http://domain.com/?css=essai/essai_css

So your problem could be a SERVER PATH TO SITE'S TEMPLATES, that you can set in template/global preferences. Or perhaps a redirect problem isnside .htaccess. 
Check the template path too.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Stéphane. I checked the server path in EE and it is fine. I cleared out my .htaccess file, even added index.php back into EE, all with no luck. Again this is only css files, strange. I'm thinking this might be a cache issue. SO I went as far as rebooting the machine allowing only my local IP in through the firewall, to avoid outside influence. And bingo, if I only hit the css file it appears. If I then go to another non-css page and then try another css file noting.

Comment: it's very weird.... I hope you problem will be resolved soon. Good luck !!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with v2.9.2. The only thing that worked for me was to

- hard code the full path to the css files into the head template,
  `href="/system/expressionengine/templates/default_site/stylesheets/base-css"` 
  instead of `href="{stylesheet='stylesheets/base-css'}"`
- enable "Save Template as File" in the stylesheet template group.